# SoftLayer API call getVirtualGuests is significantly slower than in the past

Tags: ruby, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a basic ruby program I've been using for several months now that retrieves hardware and virtualguest machine details for my account.  Up until roughly 3 days ago this always ran fine and relatively fast.  Since then it often crashes and/or the virtualguest retrieval takes 20-30 times longer than it has in the past.  What could be the issue here?  The crash stack is not very informative of the problem.

Program:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'
require 'pp'

client = SoftLayer::Client.new(:username => user, :api_key => api_key, :timeout => 999999)

account = client['Account'].object_mask("mask[virtualGuestCount,hardwareCount]").getObject()
virtual_machines_count = account["virtualGuestCount"]
bare_metal_machines_count = account["hardwareCount"]
bare_metal_machines_count_index = 0
virtual_machines_count_index = 0

for i in 0..(bare_metal_machines_count/10.0).ceil - 1
  list_of_baremetal_machines = client['Account'].result_limit(i*10,10).object_mask("mask[id, hostname, fullyQualifiedDomainName, provisionDate, datacenter[name], billingItem[recurringFee, associatedChildren[recurringFee], orderItem[description, order[userRecord[username], id]]], operatingSystem[id, softwareLicense[id, softwareDescription[longDescription]]], tagReferences[tagId, tag[name]], primaryIpAddress, primaryBackendIpAddress]").getHardware
  for x in 0..list_of_baremetal_machines.length - 1
    bare_metal_machines_count_index = bare_metal_machines_count_index + 1
    if bare_metal_machines_count_index == bare_metal_machines_count
      pp("Finished retrieving " + bare_metal_machines_count.to_s + " bare metal machines")
    end
  end
end
for i in 0..(virtual_machines_count/10.0).ceil - 1
  list_of_virtual_machines = client['Account'].result_limit(i*10,10).object_mask("mask[id, hostname, fullyQualifiedDomainName, provisionDate, datacenter[name], billingItem[recurringFee, associatedChildren[recurringFee], orderItem[description, order[userRecord[username], id]]], operatingSystem[id, softwareLicense[id, softwareDescription[longDescription]]], tagReferences[tagId, tag[name]], primaryIpAddress, primaryBackendIpAddress]").getVirtualGuests
  for x in 0..list_of_virtual_machines.length - 1
    virtual_machines_count_index = virtual_machines_count_index + 1
    if virtual_machines_count_index == virtual_machines_count
      pp("Finished retrieving " + virtual_machines_count.to_s + " virtual machines")
    end
  end
end
```

The crash looks like (the process.rb line 552 contains the getVirtualGuests call):

```
/opt/cds/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/xmlrpc/client.rb:271:in `call': An error has occurred while processing your request.  Please try again later. (XMLRPC::FaultException)
        from /opt/cds/ruby/gems/gems/softlayer_api-3.1.0/lib/softlayer/Service.rb:267:in `call_softlayer_api_with_params'
        from /opt/cds/ruby/gems/gems/softlayer_api-3.1.0/lib/softlayer/APIParameterFilter.rb:194:in `method_missing'
        from /home/dashadmin/manas/cds-health-dashboard-sensu/lib/sensu/server/process.rb:552:in `block (5 levels) in retrieve_softlayer_inventory_information'
        from /opt/cds/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/range/each.rb:7:in `each'
        from /opt/cds/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/range/each.rb:7:in `each_with_time_with_zone'
        from /home/dashadmin/manas/cds-health-dashboard-sensu/lib/sensu/server/process.rb:551:in `block (4 levels) in retrieve_softlayer_inventory_information'
        from /home/dashadmin/manas/cds-health-dashboard-sensu/lib/sensu/server/process.rb:511:in `each'
        from /home/dashadmin/manas/cds-health-dashboard-sensu/lib/sensu/server/process.rb:511:in `block (3 levels) in retrieve_softlayer_inventory_information'
        from /opt/cds/ruby/gems/gems/sensu-em-2.5.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:1054:in `call'
        from /opt/cds/ruby/gems/gems/sensu-em-2.5.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:1054:in `block in spawn_threadpool'
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this exception could be due to the amount of data that is attempting to be retrieved at once.

As first suggestion I would tell you, that you use `“result limits”` in your script. But I can see that you are using this. In that case, you may reduce the values of your result limits.
Other reason could be the query generated from that `“object masks”` is too intensive and is causing the failures. In that case it is recommended that you please reduce the values in the `“object masks”`, maybe splitting the retrieval of all those properties into multiple calls and additionally adding a cool down period in the iteration of their virtual guests.
This is pseudo code what I trying to explain:

```
for x in myVsis:
vsiId = myVsis.id
tempVsiObject1 = getVsi('[property1,property2, property3, property4]') // Call 1 with reduced properties in the mask
tempVsiObject2 = getVsi('[property5, property6, property7 ]') // Call 2 with reduced properties in the mask
tempVsiObject3 = getVsi('[property8[property9[property10[property11]]]]') // Call 3 with reduced properties in the mask
vsi = merge_objects(tempVsiObject1, tempVsiObject2, tempVsiObject3)
sleep(1) // cool down 1 second before moving to the next VSI
```

I hope this alternative help you, where the result will have in lighter queries each time.

Comment: Thanks mcruz.  The concern I have regarding your response is that my "getHardware" calls are very fast.  I also have other accounts and they seem to perform just fine.  I should have clarified that.  I seem to be having trouble with a specific account.  Have you heard of issues where specific accounts have performance problems?

Comment: I have not heard something related to SL performance problems. But if these problems are persistent, it would be a good idea to open a ticket in order to isolate the problem since a specific account has this kind of problem. My apologies for not helping more than I wanted.

Comment: Just to follow-up.  I opened a support ticket with SoftLayer and there was in fact a regression in the API that needed to be fixed.  The problem is resolved.